# I am having trouble displaying the message in the output

Tags: c#

We have to write a program in C# that makes a grocery list of items. We have to display the message from the user. Using a while loop and if/else.

```cs
using System;

namespace Homework_3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "";
            string accumulator = "$" ;
            while (input != "0")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter an item to add to your list or 0 to see the list: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                accumulator = $" {accumulator}$ { input}";
            }
            if (input == "0")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your list is empty");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your shopping list");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Thank You!");

            Console.ReadKey();
        } 

    }
}
```

I want for it to do this:

```
Enter an item to add to your shopping list or 0 to see the list: Milk
Enter an item to add to your shopping list or 0 to see the list: Bread
Enter an item to add to your shopping list or 0 to see the list: Apples
Enter an item to add to your shopping list or 0 to see the list: Cheese
Enter an item to add to your shopping list or 0 to see the list: 0 
Your Shopping List
Milk
Bread
Apples
Cheese
Thank you!
```

But instead I get this:

```
Enter an item to add to your shopping list or 0 to see the list:
milk
Enter an item to add to your shopping list or 0 to see the list:
eggs
Enter an item to add to your shopping list or 0 to see the list:
0 
Your list is empty
Thank you!
```

Comment: The program is doing exactly what you've told it to. Run it in the debugger and see if you can figure out why it's not printing the list HINT: where are you actually printing the output?

Comment: It prints "Your list is empty" because you explicitly told it to say that. Perhaps you meant to write the value of `accumulator` to the console?

Comment: Is there anyway you could give an example of what you mean? I am new to C#

Comment: This is basic code, it's hard to make it any simpler than we've already described. You just need to read your code and think about what it does. Perhaps try [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: This is a **great** opportunity to learn how to debug your own code using the **[free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: It is very difficult for the Stack Overflow community to answer a question like this in a useful way. We can all see the bug in your code, but we have no idea what led you to the bug, and it would involve way too much back-and-forth discussion to figure that out as well as to figure out what the best way to educate you on the nature of the bug and how to avoid it. This is why homework type questions are often just not appropriate here (though they are not inherently off-topic). In this case, I think you'll be much better served discussing this with your actual teacher.

Comment: I will give you this hint: do you see any place at all in your code where the `accumulator` string would be written to the screen? Even if you find an answer to that question, that won't show you _every_ issue with the code. But, it will definitely get you looking in the right place. Also: **learn to use the debugger**.

Answer (score 0):

Since this code seems to be your homework I will give you a few hints:

- `Console` has a couple of interesting methods. It would help if you would learn the difference between [`Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Console.Write`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=netframework-4.8)
- The whole `input` idea can be redone. As of now, you store only one single element. You have to be able to store multiple elements.
- If you change the `input` logic to store multiple elements, you will also have to change the way your `if` condition works.
- An alternative for `Array` and `List` is to concatenate all user inputs and "cut" them later on. You can take a look into [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___). The example in the page will give you some ideas.

Comment: Okay, its making more sense now, but I may be thinking about it too hard or feel like I've ran out of ideas as to how to store multiple elements.

Comment: @Ja'SaeLawrence you're trying to make a grocery list.  Think of how to store a list of strings in memory.

Comment: I am not allowed to use an array either. I am still working at it but it still isn't doing what I need.

Comment: @Ja'SaeLawrence  https://csharp-station.com/c-arrays-vs-lists/   maybe that link may help

Comment: Hi @Ja'SaeLawrence, I've updated my answer with another recommendation (String.Split). I hope this helps.